# 'Incomplete final line' warning when trying to read gender.gmt file into R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to read all lines from the gmt file but I am always getting the same warning.

Here is the command and warning:

```
C <- readLines( file("~/gender.gmt") )
```

Warning message:

```
In readLines(file("~/gender.gmt")) :incomplete final line found on '~/gender.gmt'
```

I couldn't understand how to complete this incomplete line and what does it mean?

Here is some information I tried but of no help:

Incomplete final line when trying to read csv in R

Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: It is a warning not an error. The last line of your file does not end with "end-of-line" characters which on Windows is Carriage return + Linefeed. On Linux and OS X it is a single Linefeed. You probably can correct it by getting the file in your (plain text) editor, positioning the cursor at the end of the last line and pressing Enter. Then save the file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion in handling the warning. I had done editing the gmt file.

Comment: then @jaap do you know about this one? `D <- readLines( file("~/gender.gct") )` When I `> View(D)` Error in View : 'names' attribute [11143] must be the same length as the vector [1]